# Can you map any value to any value in javascript using plain object?

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary

I've just playing around with javascript objects,
and discovered that you can set anything as an object key.
I've tried this using a range of values,
and all worked well while I was using array bracket property access...
So, my question is can you map any value to
any value in javascript using plain object?

Comment: map any value to any value in javascript? can u be more clear..

Comment: ... like use objects or non primitives as keys on an object.

Comment: If you are using KnockoutJS then it is possible to map values from JSON or from DOM elements

Comment: can you simply do this:

var

 o   = {},

 p1  = { prop1:11, prop2:12 },
 p2  = window,
 p3  = ['a', 'z'],
 p4  = document.body,
 p5  = null,
 p6  = undefined,
 p7  = NaN,
 p8  = Function,
 p9  = document.firstChild,
 p10 = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
 p11 = function () {};

 o[p1]  = 1;
 o[p2]  = 2;
 o[p3]  = 3;
 o[p4]  = 4;
 o[p5]  = 5;
 o[p6]  = 6;
 o[p7]  = 7;
 o[p8]  = 8;
 o[p9]  = 9;
 o[p10] = 10;
 o[p11] = 11;

Comment: Keys cannot be objects, it is just a string not any variable or object. So `var o = {}; o.window = 10;` will take `window` as string not the actual window object.

Comment: Hey who said key can not be Object.here is fiddle [Object as Keys](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/bah7T/)

Comment: I guess Digvijay Yadav has the point, 
try adding:

for ( var l in myObj ) alert( typeof l );

to that fidle code, 
it says 'string' in each case...
objects are converted to strings before setting them as prop names...